# How can I make, from 1 list of string, a DataFrame with index each unique couple made from this list?

Tags: python, pandas

For exemple I have the list:
players = ['thomas', 'ryan', 'alice', 'nicolas']

how can I create a DataFrame that has for index every unique couple from this list ? 
like this :

```py
    player_1    player_2    results
0   thomas      ryan    
1   thomas      alice   
2   thomas      nicolas 
3   ryan        alice   
4   ryan        nicolas 
5   alice       nicolas
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(index=['|'.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(players,2)],columns=['result'])` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone (for editing my question with good layout and for itertools answers)

I was first thinking of something with pandas pivot but not efficient.

The code below is exactly what I needed

```
In [1]:
from itertools import combinations 
import pandas as pd

players = ['thomas', 'ryan', 'alice', 'nicolas']

df_rencontres = pd.DataFrame(list(combinations(players, 2)),
                             columns=['player_1', 'player_2']
                            ).set_index(['player_1', 'player_2'])

df_rencontres['results'] = ''
df_rencontres
```

```py
Out [1]:

player_1    player_2    results
thomas      ryan    
thomas      alice   
thomas      nicolas 
ryan        alice   
ryan        nicolas 
alice       nicolas
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) library, specifically combinations for your case.